# yii2 retrieve records with model is a variable

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I have a piece of code:

```
$objs = $model::find()
                ->where(['id' => $data['item']])
                ->all();
```

with $model is variable.. so how to do like that?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just replace *::* with *->*

```
$model->find()
->where(['id' => $data['item']])
->all();
```

Comment: so, we have to new a object ?

`$model = new User(); $model->find() ...` 
Thanks